# Proof of the chain rule for weak differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The following lemma is cited from the PDE book by Gilbarg and Trudinger, and in the statement, $\Omega$ denotes a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

[image]

The spirit of the proof is OK with me, but the estimates involved really confuse me. Firstly, how can the inequality in (A) happen? Let us forget the integration, the supremum, the absolute value, etc. Is it possible to build something like
$$f(u_m)-f(u)=f'(...)(u_m-u)?$$
More precisely, is there any counterpart of the mean value theorem in sequences of functions? Thank you.

Here's my attempt to deuce the inequality:
\begin{align}
|f(u_m)-f(u)|&=\left|\int_u^{u_m}f'(t)\mathrm{d}t\right|\\
&\leq\int_u^{u_m}|f'(t)|\mathrm{d}t\tag{the most dangerous step I think}\\
&\leq(\sup|f'|)\int_u^{u_m}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=(\sup|f'|)(u_m-u)
\end{align}
Is anything wrong? Thank you.

> Here comes my worst nightmare. I want to deduce (B), and to this end, I write
>   \begin{align}
> f'(u_m(x_2))(\mathrm{D}u_m)(x_2)-f'(u(x_1))(\mathrm{D}u)(x_1)&=f'(u_m(x_2))(\mathrm{D}u_m)(x_2)-f'(u_m(x_1))(\mathrm{D}u_m)(x_1)+f'(u_m(x_1))(\mathrm{D}u_m)(x_1)\\
> &\quad-f'(u(x_1))(\mathrm{D}u)(x_1)+f'(u(x_2))(\mathrm{D}u)(x_2)-f'(u(x_2))(\mathrm{D}u)(x_2)\\
> &=[D(f\circ u_m)]_{x_1}^{x_2}+f'(u_m(x_1))(\mathrm{D}u_m)(x_1)\\
> &\quad+[D(f\circ u)]_{x_1}^{x_2}-f'(u(x_2))(\mathrm{D}u)(x_2).
> \end{align}
>   This is still far from the desired result. Is there anything I can do? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Saying that $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ (which is one of the hypothesis given in the lemma) means that there exists a continuous function $g$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb R$,
$$
f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xg(x) \ dx.
$$
Thus,
$$
f(u_m)-f(u)=\int_u^{u_m}g(x)\ dx.
$$
Therefore by the triangle inequality (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) for example)
$$
|f(u_m)-f(u)|\leq \|g(x)\|_{\infty}|u_m-u|,
$$
where I write $\|g(x)\|_{\infty}=\sup_x |g(x)|$ for the $\infty$ norm.

On the other hand, by the fundamental theorem of calculus $g(x)=f'(x)$, so this proves (A).

Comment: Sir, can you tell me where the absolute value came from? I ended up with $|f(u_m)-f(u)|\leq \|g(x)\|_{\infty}\color{red}{(u_m-u)}$. Did I miss anything? Thank you.

Comment: The absolute value is necessary since switching the bounds on top and bottom ($u$ replaced with $u_m$) will negate the integral. Note also that there is no guarantee which of $u$ or $u_m$ is larger, so without the absolute value the inequality is obviously false (right side can be negative and left side is always non-negative).